# Should I discreticize continuous variables in linear mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, fixed-effects-model, binning

I would like to use linear mixed models for my analysis.

My model looks like:

```
Response ~ Group1 + Group2 + Age + Gender + Weight + (1|Subject)
```

I would like to know if I can use continue values for Age and Weight or if it is better to group them and use Age and Weight as categorical variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed before and you can use the search function to find good discussions on the topic. In short, it is better to not group the continuous variables for several reasons, among others that you lose information and that the groups are probably not representing anything meaningful (there is no real difference between an individual aged 69 and one aged 70, but if you create categorical age groups, the prediction for these two individuals might differ).

So the easiest option is to include age and weight as they are. But the relationship might not be linear and you should plot age and weight to your response variable and get a visual impression. You can then try adding polynomial terms:

```
Age + I(Age^2)
Age + I(Age^2) + I(Age^3)
```

And see if this improves the model. You can also try using regression splines, for instance by using the gamm() model from the mgcv package:

```
s(Age) + s(Weight)
```

Which will model non-linear relationships to your response variable.

Comment: Thanks, How do I know then what is the "reference" age for which the intercept is calculated?

Comment: Good question! I have never considered that as I'm usually not that concerned about the intercept..

Comment: You'll have to look at the plot to see at what age(s) the line crosses 0. Those are the ages that the intercept refers to, so to speak.